# What is the fastest way to make an array from a db column?

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to put all the elements of a database column of an ActiveRecord model into an array. I do so like this:

```
code_array = []
Language.all.each do |lang|
  code_array<<lang.code
end

=> ["af", "sq", "ar", "hy", "az", "eu", "be", "bn", "bs", "bg", "ca", "ceb", "ny", "zh-CN", "zh-TW", "hr", "cs", "da", "nl", "en", "eo", "et", "tl", "fi", "fr", "gl", "ka", "de", "el", "gu", "ht", "ha", "iw", "hi", "hmn", "hu", "is", "ig", "id", "ga", "it", "ja", "jw", "kn", "kk", "km", "ko", "lo", "la", "lv", "lt", "mk", "mg", "ms", "ml", "mt", "mi", "mr", "mn", "my", "ne", "no", "fa", "pl", "pt", "ma", "ro", "ru", "sr", "st", "si", "sk", "sl", "so", "es", "su", "sw", "sv", "tg", "ta", "te", "th", "tr", "uk", "ur", "uz", "vi", "cy", "yi", "yo", "zu"]
```

But this must be possible with more elegant and/or less code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

```
Language.pluck(:code)
```

Incedentally, even if you don't use pluck, you could significantly improve your code by changing:

```
code_array = []
Language.all.each do |lang|
  code_array<<lang.code
end
```

to

```
Language.all.map(&:code)
```

Your code is iterating over all the results, taking the field `code` and pushing it onto an array, and then moving to the next element.  It is often more efficient to map a function to a set or array.

Comment: Your proposed improvement is purely aesthetic. Underlying operations are still the same. Meaning, it is not "more efficient".

Comment: Perfect answer! I never heard of the `pluck` method and it is what I was looking for when writing this question. I could have thought of map though.  Somehow `map` is difficult to get into my active ehh repertoire.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Is there a more efficient way to do it? If not, I am very happy with this aesthetic improvement.

Comment: @Flip: yes, it's certainly nicer code than what you had. I was just pointing out a false claim.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: No worries, I wasn't assuming anything else. The question now is if there is a better way?

Comment: @Flip: `pluck` is definitely the way to go. If `Language` has lots of other columns, you can select only the needed one. Something like: `Language.select('code').map(&:code)`.